# Is there a way to display the same URL on a php redirect?

Tags: php, html

Basically i want my users to not be able to access the next page until they have agreed to the TOS, however even with a script for accepting the TOS, obviously users can still type "example.com/nextpage" to avoid accepting the TOS. So is there a way I can redirect the users to another page after they have accepted the terms without displaying the URL of the page they are being redirected to?

Thanks,

Comment: Sure, put the accept checkbox in a form that then does a `header("Location: nextpage.php")` redirect but only if the checkbox was checked

Comment: Save their acceptance in the session. `nextpage` checks that session value and sends them back if they haven't gone through the formal acceptance process yet.

Comment: Yes, there is. But what's to keep them from sharing that url with people not agreeing to the TOS? Use a session, store the acceptance of the TOS, don't allow people which have not (yet) agreed to it & redirect them back to that page. Don't filter on 'should not go further', filter on 'should not be here' in pages.

Answer (score 1):

No.

However, you could set a cookie that records their agreement, then simply reload the same page.

If your page finds the cookie with agreement set, it renders the normal page. If not, it renders the ToS form.

This will allow you to enforce ToS agreement without being shortcutted (unless someone manually assigns a cookie to themselves, but that is far beyond the majority of users)

Comment: Well, they could assign a cookie to themselves, but if you do it properly the cookie itself doesn't say that they agreed. It would be more like a session id, and then you can store/check in your database whether you've confirmed that the session id belongs to a user who clicked "I agree"